# Calculate product of disjoint cycles

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, permutations, cyclic-groups

I'm working on the following problem:
Let $a = (1, 5, 3)(2, 4)$ and $b = (2, 4, 5)$ be permutations in $S_6$. Calculate the product $ba$. Answer with a product of disjoint cycles.
$ba $

This is what I got, but it is wrong:
$(2 4)(3 1 5)$

How can you think?

Comment: I don't know that... I submit and it just says that it's the wrong answer

Comment: try with $(1,2,5,3)$

Comment: incorrect :(, think its supposed to be at lest two brackets

Comment: no.. it still says ")" is expected, so I guess the format is not right

Comment: $ba=(2,4,5)(1,5,3)(2,4)=(1,2,5,3) $

Comment: Still wrong idk why, but it gives error: "Symbol ")" expected."

Comment: how did you get your solution?

Comment: βα=(2 4 5)(1 5 3)(2 4). (2 4 5)(1 5 3)(2 4)→(2 4 5)(1 5 3)→(2 4)(1 5 3)→(2 4)(3 1 5)

Comment: I'm new to this so probably wrong though

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing sorry

Comment: It may be your book multiplies compositions tight to left.

Comment: @coffeemath good point

Comment: @Kei  Len  What is the "it" which is telling  you your answer is wrong ,  and giving you the error  "Symbol ")" expected" ?  Is it an application that's available online ?  What "its" full name?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the answer to this kind of question depends on whether you write a permutation on the left or the right of its argument - you'll need to check your textbook or course notes for which convention you are supposed to use. E.g., if $\theta = (1\,2\,3)(2\,4)$, then $\theta 2 = 4$, while $2\theta = 3$. How did I get that? Think of feeding $2$ through $\theta$ either from the right or from the left: working from the right, $(2\,4)$ maps $2$ to  $4$ and $(1\,2\,3)$ leaves $4$ unchanged, while working from the left $(1\,2\,3)$ maps $2$ to $3$ and then $(2\,4)$ leaves $3$ unchanged. To get the disjoint cycle representation (having decided whether you are working from the left or the right), you fix a starting point, say $1$ and then keep passing it through $\theta$ until you get back to $1$. E.g., working form the right you get tyhat $\theta$ sends $1$ to $2$, $2$ to $4$, $4$ to $3$ and then $3$ back to $1$. So $\theta = (1\,2\,4\,3)$. In general, you might have missed one of the letters, so you'd carry on with the next letter that you haven't visited. (Apologies for the terminology: "letter" is the standard term for the things that permutations permute, but we usually write them as numbers.)

In your example, you have $a = (1\,5\,3)(2\,4)$ $b = (2\,4\,5)$. Using the above reasoning I get that:

$\quad ba = (1\,2\,5\,3)$ (working right to left, dropping the trivial cycle $(4)$ that the process above gives).

$\quad ba = (1\,5\,4\,3)$ (working left to right, again dropping the trivial cycle $(2)$).

Comment: you should calculate the product of b*a not a*b

Comment: I fixed it. Unsurprisingly, changing $ab$ to $ba$ swaps the answers round. Do you see why?